# How do build use this library React table, react-window and react-window-infinite-loader (infiniloader)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying load huge content inside the react table but react-window scroll not working getting glitching scroll. Please help on this issue.

> I want active below steps
> 1. I want to target table body scroll and load the data
> 2. I want use react-window inside the table body

I want active below steps
1. I want to target table body scroll and load the data
2. I want use react-window inside the table body

```
export const DataTable = ({columns, data, isItemLoadeds, update}) => {
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);
  const {getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow} =
    useTable(
      {
        columns,
        data,
      },
      useSortBy,
      useExpanded,
      useRowSelect
      //useBlockLayout
    );

  const RenderRow = ({index, style}) => {
    const row = rows[index];
    prepareRow(row);
    return (
      <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
        {row.cells.map((cell) => {
          return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
        })}
      </tr>
    );
  };

  const renderRow = ({index, style}) => {
    const row = rows[index];
    prepareRow(row);

    return (
      <div className="table-row custom-row" {...row.getRowProps()}>
        {row.cells.map((cell) => {
          return (
            <div className="table-cell" {...cell.getCellProps()}>
              {cell.render("Cell")}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  };
  const isItemLoaded = (index) => !isItemLoadeds || index < data.length;
  return (
    <div className="data-table-container-generating-bom">
      <InfiniteLoader
        isItemLoaded={isItemLoaded}
        itemCount={data.length} // Total number of items (estimate or from your data)
        loadMoreItems={update}
      >
        {({onItemsRendered, ref}) => (
          <FixedSizeList
            height={400} // Adjust the height as needed
            itemCount={data.length} // Use the number of rows you have
            itemSize={35} // Adjust the row height as needed
            onItemsRendered={onItemsRendered}
            ref={ref}
            {...getTableProps()}
          >
            {renderRow}
          </FixedSizeList>
        )}
      </InfiniteLoader>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I am tried to add useBlockLayout but it could not work. Most of the way I have tried but could not help past a week. Please help me on this issue.